# Accessing hierarchical columns in pandas after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, hierarchical-data

I use pandas for grouping a dataset. When I aggregate different columns with different functions I'm getting a hierarchical column-structure.

```
G1 = df.groupby('date').agg({'col1': [sum, np.mean], 'col2': 'sum', 'col3': np.mean})
```

results in:

```
            col1               col2       col3
               sum      mean      sum       mean
date
2000-11-01    1701  1.384052    82336  54.222945
2000-11-02   11101  1.447894   761963  70.027260
2000-11-03   11285  1.479418   823355  77.984268
```

I couldn't find too much about this resulting structure in the docs unfortunately. The only thing I found in pandas docs was the hierarchical multi-index.

How can I access the values?
Currently I do: `X['col1']['mean']` to access the whole `Series`

```
2000-11-01   1.384052   
2000-11-02   1.447894  
2000-11-03   1.479418
```

and thus `X['col1']['mean'][1]` to get the value `1.447894`, but I wonder about the performance, because this code first slices `col1` (X['col1']) which results in a view/copy (dunno which one in this case) containing actually 2 columns, and then there is yet another slice of the `mean`-column.

Any tips?
And where can I find more about the creation of the hierarchical columns in the docs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advice is to do these in one pass (without chaining), this especially allows you to do assignment (rather than assigning to a view and the modification being garbage collected).

Access a MultiIndex* column as a tuple:

```
In [11]: df[('col1', 'mean')]
Out[11]:
date
2000-11-01    1.384052
2000-11-02    1.447894
2000-11-03    1.479418
Name: (col1, mean), dtype: float64
```

and a specific value using loc:

```
In [12]: df.loc['2000-11-01', ('col1', 'mean')]
Out[12]: 1.3840520000000001
```

(To mix labels, loc, and position, iloc, you have to use ix)

```
In [13]: df.ix[0, ('col1', 'mean')]
Out[13]: 1.3840520000000001
```

**This **is** a MultiIndex.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah so I was right with my assumption to avoid chaining. Thx for clarifying that these are actually so called MultiIndexes; I thought this name is only applied for MultiIndexing in rows... But I see the analogy, especially because one can easily transpose a DataFrame (and thus still keep the MultiIndex).